# How to filter an array of arrays and just return part of each inner array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array of arrays:

```
const myArray = [ ['1', 'first'], ['2', 'second'], ['3', 'third'], ['4', 'fourth'] ]
```

I want to return an array like:

```
[ 'first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth' ]
```

I'm trying the following filter:

```
const res = myArray.filter( elm => elm[1] )
```

but it doesn't return the desired filter, just return the same...

Comment: Use `map()` instead of `filter()` and you're done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is used to create a subset of an array containing elements that pass a certain requirements test.

[.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is used create a new array consisting of the results of passing the elements through a function.

The following should work as you intend:

```
const res = myArray.map(elm => elm[1]);
```